# PHP image crop outside image bounds gives black bar

Tags: php, crop

When I use this to crop the image I get a horrible black bar at the top:

```
$image_new = imagecrop($image_source,['x'=>235,'y'=>-50,'width'=>1650,'height'=>1650]);
```

I also tried this (same result):

```
imagecopy($image_new,$image_source, 0, 0, 235, -50, 1650, 1650);
```

Obviously the -50 is sampling from outside the canvas.

It seems when you crop in PHP GDimage outside of the bounds...you get black bars

How do I solve this problem? I need to get alpha instead.

Comment: It seems to be limitation of GD? I tried to add `imagealphablending()`, `imagesavealpha()`, `imagefill()` transparent color, `imagecolortransparent()` on the filled one.
All of these on source image object and destination image object but none of them are working.